# XQuery with if condition in for loop

Tags: xquery, marklogic, exist-db

I have written xquery to return results in normal way.

```
let $results := //data:data
return 
  <result>
  {
    for $i in $results
    return
      <documentInformation>
        <id>{data($i/DATA:ID)}</id>
        <status>{data($i/@status)}</status>
        <title>{data($i/data:title)}</title>
        <displayName>{data($i/DATA:DISPLAYNAME)}</displayName>
      </documentInformation>
  }
  </result>
```

Now, I have to filter out the results **in for loop with some condition** like

```
(pseudo logic)
if id = 'abc' and status ="closed"  
then skip the row
else add row.
```

I have tried several ways. but could not run the query..

Comment: Please read [How to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and [ask]. Your question lacks example input, which will either lead to long discussions ("still does not work for me") or makes the question hardly answerable at all. Anyway, I'm very sure you don't need an if statement at all, have a look at predicates and the where clause, which are both _very_ basic and important XQuery language constructs. Don't write "I have tried several ways." Post _what_ your tried, and how it fails!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<result>
{
  for $i in //data:data
  where fn:not($i/DATA:ID = 'abc' and $i/@status = "closed")
  return
    <documentInformation>
      <id>{data($i/DATA:ID)}</id>
      <status>{data($i/@status)}</status>
      <title>{data($i/data:title)}</title>
      <displayName>{data($i/DATA:DISPLAYNAME)}</displayName>
    </documentInformation>
}
</result>
```

Note that the XPath `//data:data` may have a lot of work to do, but that's a separate matter.

Comment: Might be helpful to note a couple alternatives. In some situations it may be more efficient to write a predicate instead of a where clause: `for $i in //data:data[not(DATA:ID = 'abc') and @status = "closed")]`. In other situations it's convenient to nest inside the return, as `return if not($i/DATA:ID = 'abc' and $i/@status = "closed") then $a else $b`

Answer (score 4):

You Can also use `if` condition  instead of `where`

```
<result>
{
    for $i in //data:data
    return 
        if($i/DATA:ID != 'abc' and $i/@status != "closed")
        then
        (
            <documentInformation>
            <id>{data($i/DATA:ID)}</id>
            <status>{data($i/@status)}</status>
            <title>{data($i/data:title)}</title>
            <displayName>{data($i/DATA:DISPLAYNAME)}</displayName>
            </documentInformation>
        )
        else ()
}
</result>
```

Comment: Can you put an iff around a tag?